# WPF label counterpart for HTML "for" attribute

Tags: wpf, label, target, for-attribute

Is there some attribute in WPF that I can add to  element, so when I click it the target control get focus? The closest thing I have found is 'Target', but it works only with access keys and clicking it has no effect.

Comment: Somewhat related.  Labels have the [Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label.target?view=netframework-4.8) property, that points to the element which receives focus when the user presses the label's access key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but an [attached behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx) could be made to work for this.

Answer (score 2):

override the Label control

```
public class LabelEx : Label
{
    public LabelEx() : base() {}

    protected override void OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Target != null) Target.Focus();
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
}
```