# Click on label to select radiobutton in WPF with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-experience

I'm learning WPF, and am wondering if there's an idiomatic way to create a label that, when clicked, toggles a checkbox or radio button. I was somewhat surprised that the `Target` attribute on `Label` doesn't do this. I am using the MVVM pattern (with the MVVMFoundation framework.)

Comment: Do you mean clicking on the content (for example a text label) of a checkbox or radiobutton should set it as checked? Isn't that how it works by default?

Comment: Oh my. I didn't realize you can set the content of a radiobutton or checkbox, how embarassing. I've been thinking like a web developer.

Comment: There's a good example [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681960/wpf-label-counterpart-for-html-for-attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target property sets the focus to the target element when the labels pre-defined access key is pressed so does not do what you want.

Off the top of my head I would suggest creating a button and using a Style to make it look like a label.  You can add 'content' to a checkbox though and this will check the box when clicked.