# Clicking on a Label to focus another control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, click, label

I have taken a break from WPF for about a year and I am stumped by this simple problem. I swear there was an easy way to tell a label to focus to another control when it is clicked.

```
 <StackPanel>
    <Label Target="TextBox1">Label Text</Label>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" />
</StackPanel>
```

When the user clicks on "Label Text" I want the TextBox to receive focus. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should make use of the Target property:

```
<Label Content="_Stuff:" Target="{x:Reference TextBox1}"
       MouseLeftButtonUp="Label_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" />
```

```
private void Label_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 1) //Note that this is a lie, this does not check for a "real" click
    {
        var label = (Label)sender;
        Keyboard.Focus(label.Target);
    }
}
```

The whole point of using a Label in the first place instead of a TextBlock is to make use of its associative functionality, see the [reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx).

About my note, i asked a question about how to get a real click [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830164/what-is-the-best-way-to-simulate-a-click-with-mouseup-mousedown-events-or-other), if you are curious.

Answer (score 2):

I found the code I used to use for this and figured I would share it in case it is useful for anyone else.

```
public class LabelEx : Label
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Target != null)
        {
            Target.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the [Label's Target property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.target.aspx) may allow you to do this without defining your own dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

can't you do that with the shortcut key combination

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=textbox1}" Content="_Name"/>
    <TextBox Name="textbox1" Height="25" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading [WPF label counterpart for HTML "for" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681960/wpf-label-counterpart-for-html-for-attribute), you'd need an attached behavior to do that.